# No output from pycharm profiling when running a Flask container

Tags: python, pycharm

Running PyCharm 4.5.3 Build #141.1899 Professional Edition and licensed. I run a Flask app using the profiler command using a configuration similar to:

```
python app.py
```

which looks like:

```
def create_app():
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static')
app.register_blueprint(
    consumer_v1.bp,
    url_prefix='/consumer/v1')
return app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5001)
```

When I goto "Run -> Profile App" I see the following on the console:

```
   /Users/james/.virtualenvs/trustmile-api/bin/python   /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/profiler/run_profiler.py 127.0.0.1 49537 /Users/james/Documents/workspace/trustmile-backend/trustmile/api_stubs/api_stubs/__init__.py
Starting cProfile profiler

2015-09-01 07:00:25,717 INFO  [werkzeug][MainThread]  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5001/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2015-09-01 07:00:25,723 INFO  [werkzeug][MainThread]  * Restarting with stat
2015-09-01 07:00:32,801 INFO  [werkzeug][Thread-1] 127.0.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2015 07:00:32] "POST /consumer/v1/account/password HTTP/1.1" 403 -
Snapshot saved to /Users/XXXX/Library/Caches/PyCharm40/snapshots/trustmile-backend5.pstat
Process finished with exit code 0
```

However nothing is shown in the UI as shown below.

[image]

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Used yappi and that worked. Works with that framework.

Comment: Solved it for me too, you should post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To fix this I simply installed [yappi](https://bitbucket.org/sumerc/yappi/) instead of the default python profiler.

`pip install yappi`

I hope this works for you too!